# WPF binding and animation question

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, binding

I want to put Label (or textbox) on my window that is text and is background binding to some properties (string for text and color or some brush to background) in the viewmodel datacontext.

I change the properties when something happened. for example if exception raised the background will be res and the text will be "exception" etc.

I also want that the label/textbox will flash in cyclicality when the background color changed.

I know how to bind color but how can i bind brush? and I have no idea about the animation...

I'll appreciate your help

Comment: For animation there is storyboard.  What happens with you try to bind to a brush?  Do you have a property that returns a brush?

Comment: to bind color i just need string property with the color name. how it can done with RadialGardientBrush?

Comment: Color is not a string property.  Brush color is the format System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Pink.  You need to bind to a property of type System.Windows.Media.Brush.  If your binding source returns string then you need to use a converter for string to System.Windows.Media.Brush.  Do you have some code samples with specific question?

Comment: string property work fine for me with a string property. i'll try to find how to bind brush. anyway my big problem us the animation. do you have idea how to do this.

Comment: How animation works is a very broad question and I would refer you to the documentation.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx  SO is more for specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using something like Blend for animations.  It makes things so much simpler.  I have tried doing it in Visual Studio, and it is painful since you can't show your changes in the designer and test the animation without running the program.

Grab a [free trial version of Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/try-it/), and give it a whirl.